# Change values in multiple columns with unique value and merge into single column (R)

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Let's say I have a dataset (ds) with 4 rows with 3 variables as seen below:

```
ds
x1  x2  x3
 1   0   0
 0   0   1
 0   1   0
 0   0   1
```

How do I change the "1" to a unique value for each column and combine them into a single column?

So, the first step:

```
x1  x2  x3
 1   0   0
 0   0   3
 0   2   0
 0   0   3
```

Then, the second step (creating `x4`):

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
 1   0   0   1
 0   0   3   3
 0   2   0   2
 0   0   3   3
```

I have a lot more variables than this, I just want to know how to minimize the number of lines I write so it's not like 10+ lines.

Comment: This is almost surely a bad idea; `x1..x3` look like dummies/one-hot variables for the underlying categorical variable `x4`. This sounds like an [XY problem[(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you need to do this? You could always change  each set of dummies back to their categorical variable instead.

Comment: So there was a problem with how data was recorded. So for a single item measure on a scale from 1 to 7, each value was recorded with it's own column. So anyone who responded with a 3 was scored as a 1 on the third column, a response of 6 as a 1 on the sixth column, etc.
So I need to collapse them all into a single column with the appropriate value.

Comment: Daniel: that is not a "problem with how data was recorded", **it's a very standard technique (one-hot/dummy variable encoding)**. (e.g. if the information came from a multi-choice form/survey/webform). So you're simply asking **"How to reverse 'one-hot' encoding in dataframe columns?"**

Comment: smci: Yeah thank you, I am just now realizing that after talking with the original owner of the dataset who didn't realize that that is what they did. It was a "problem" because that was not intentional. But yes, I appreciate you letting me know the technical term for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df <- read.table(text="x1  x2  x3
1   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
0   0   1", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df <- df*col(df)
df$x4 <- rowSums(df)

  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  1  0  0  1
2  0  0  3  3
3  0  2  0  2
4  0  0  3  3
```

Comment: If the data frame is too big (million rows), then the `df <- df*col(df)` can be replaced with `df <- sweep(x = df, MARGIN = 2, STATS = t(1:ncol(df)), FUN = '*')` to make it memory efficient.  Also, the last line of code will be problematic if there is more than one non-zero value in any given row because it is returning the sum of each row.  OP needs to decide what is the expected result.